# Teaching an alternate definition for a compactness via the induction principle

Tags: topology

In [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2yc5am/topological_compactness_is_an_induction_principle/) post on Reddit, a user proposes an alternate definition of compactness, as an "induction principle":

> A topological space $X$ is compact iff given a statement $P$ whose
>   truth or falsity is defined on open subsets of $X$, we have $P(X)$ as
>   soon as
>
> 1. For all $x \in X$ there exists open $U \ni x$ such that $P(U)$.
> 2. $P(U_1), \dotsc, P(U_n) \implies P(U_1 \cup \dotsb \cup U_n)$.

To me this seems like such a drastically better definition of compactness: more intuitive, more mathematical, more to the point. The statement in terms of open covers is useful in proofs, but it should be secondary to this.

Any thoughts/opinions? Why don't we teach compactness this way, except that that's the way it's always been done?

Comment: "Any thoughts/opinions?" question should be avoided here,  but the second part is alright. Additionally, "pedagogically terrible" is a bit of a stretch. I think a better title is "Teaching an alternate definition for a compact topological space via the induction principal?"

Comment: Look at the compactness theorem in logic, and consider proof versions using topology, standard methods taught in mathematical logic, and using this definition.  Then try some proofs of applications of compactness, both in logic and topology.  Then come tell us what you think of the new definition.  Gerhard "Even Better, Write It Up" Paseman, 2015.03.24

Comment: Oh, almost forgot: after doing the above, consider how you would relate sequential compactness, paracompactness, countably compact, and so on to the new definition?  If that's too easy, consider the use of compact in other realms, e.g. compact elements of lattices, and see if that helps things make sense. Gerhard "Just Asking For The World" Paseman, 2015.03.24

Comment: Noetherian equivalence with all subspaces being compact might be another challenge. The concept of taking a collection of sets, unioning them up, and picking out a finite number of them that have the same union is a critical idea that shouldn't be hidden in the definition.

Comment: Guys, I don't think Eric is saying to *never* introduce the standard definition.  Just use this definition first, and develop the standard one as equivalent.

Comment: How would you prove $[0,1]$ is compact with this definition?

Comment: It's not clear from the question how much this definition is meant to replace the standard definition.  The original title suggested that this definition was to be preferred over the standard.  Indeed, this new one may have its advantages, but to understand them, try using them in a formal setting (outside of class, by using it) before trying to use it in a classroom setting (which may still introduce problems even if it helps to clarify one teaching example).  A short (and maybe false) answer is that it is untested.  Gerhard "Show Me How It Works" Paseman, 2015.03.24

Comment: Also, as a technical nitpick: first-order logic has a compactness theorem while second-order logic doesn't.  In order for this to be used properly, one has to exercise care on the properties P for which the statement is being used.  I think the posting gives a good first attempt and may lead to some good intuition, but without the appropriate technical restrictions it may also lead many astray.  In particular, is X a set of members that don't contain themselves?  Gerhard "Ill-Foundedness: Don't Get Me Started" Paseman, 2015.03.24

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Perhaps your thoughts could be organized into a good answer for the question.

Comment: I get the feeling this is more enticing than it truly is - if I wanted to show something like, "If the derivative of $f$ is positive on all of $[0,1]$, $f(1)\geq f(0)$" then I can argue clearly from compactness to find a finite increasing sequence starting at $0$ and ending at $1$, but I'm not sure how I'd use the new definition. Ideally, $P(U)$ could be "$f$ is increasing on $U$", but I'm not sure how to reach condition (1), since this is pretty much equivalent to what we were trying to prove originally. It can't be "$f(x)\geq f(0)$ for $x\in U$, since proving (1) would give $f(1)\geq f(0)$.

Comment: @EricAuld The proof I was thinking of was proving it from definitions and not invoking any particular theorems other than compactness: "If $f'(x)>0$ then by the definition of the derivative, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that for all $a\in U$ we have $a<x\Rightarrow f(a)<f(x)$ and $a>x\Rightarrow f(a)>f(x)$). The set of such neighborhoods is an open cover so we choose a finite subcover and construct a finite sequence of $x$ with overlapping neighborhoods" - which relies on a property of *pointed* open sets, not just open sets and really translates badly to the new definition

Comment: @KCd I can't think of a better proof than the standard one, using the least upper bound property...but this definition doesn't make that proof more complicated, in my estimation.

Comment: When first proposed in the early 1900's, the Heine-Borel theorem was thought of as "continuous induction" for an interval of real numbers.  Also see: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/4424/442

Comment: @Meelo, would one really prove that using compactness?  It seems like a case for the mean-value theorem, which has more to do with *completeness* than compactness.